# Append a byte to a string?

Tags: go

How do you append a byte to a string in Go?

```
var ret string
var b byte
ret += b

invalid operation: ret += b (mismatched types string and byte)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to ThunderCats answer.. you could initialize a `bytes.Buffer` from a string ... allowing you to continue appending bytes as you see fit:

```
buff := bytes.NewBufferString(ret)

// maybe buff.Grow(n) .. if you hit perf issues?

buff.WriteByte(b)
buff.WriteByte(b)

// ...

result := buff.String()
```

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few options:

```
// append byte as slice
ret += string([]byte{b})

// append byte as rune
ret += string(rune(b))

// convert string to byte slice, append byte to slice, convert back to string
ret = string(append([]byte(ret), b))
```

Benchmark to see which one is best.

If you want to append more than one byte, then break the second option into multiple statements and append to the []byte:

```
buf := []byte(ret)    // convert string to byte slice
buf = append(buf, b)  // append byte to slice
buf = append(buf, b1) // append byte to slice
... etc
ret = string(buf)     // convert back to string
```

If you want to append the rune `r`, then it's a little simpler:

```
 ret += string(r)
```

Strings are immutable. The code above creates a new string that is a concatenation of the original string and a byte or rune.

Answer (score 5):

It's a lot simpler than either of the other answers:

```
var ret string = "test"
var b byte = 'a'
ret += string(b)

// returns "testa"
```

That is, you can just cast an integer to a string and it will treat the integer as a rune (byte is an integer type).  An then you can just concatenate the resulting string with `+`

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ktnUg70M-I

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Golang.

```
package main

    import (
    
        "fmt"
    )
    
    func main() {
        byteArr := []byte{1,2,5,4}
        stringStr := "Test"
        output:= fmt.Sprintf("%v %v",byteArr,stringStr)
        fmt.Println("Output: ",output)
    }
```

> Output

```
Output:  [1 2 5 4] Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strings.Builder`:

```
package main
import "strings"

func main() {
   var b strings.Builder
   b.WriteByte('!')
   println(b.String() == "!")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Builder.WriteByte